# Parse.com email verification not sending for Yahoo & Optonline

Tags: email, parse-platform, dns

I made an app using parse, and am using email verification in it. I have a bug where it is not sending email verifications to @yahoo.com & @optonline.net emails. Those are the two I found to not be working. It is working for all other emails.

It says to do the following stuff below, but I am very new to web coding, and so I have no idea how to complete the following tasks. Could someone walk me through them? And if that is not even how I should fix the error, what would be the fix?

To ensure that mail providers don't incorrectly mark emails sent on behalf of your app as spam, we recommend you add DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) and SPF (Sender Policy Framework) records to your DNS records.

```
Run the following in your terminal: dig +short k1._domainkey.parse.com txt for the most up-to-date DKIM value.
Add the following to your SPF or TXT record: v=spf1 include:parseapps.com ~all
```

Comment: Others are experiencing this.  Someone has filed a bug, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1451634591805828/

Comment: Also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282983/parse-cant-send-verification-email-to-yahoo-mail (closed, probably wrongly, imo).

Comment: I thought the same, sending simultaneous emails to several addresses reached @yahoo.com domain last ( ~ 5min ), the rest got mails instantly. EDIT: just saw the issue is closed anyways